# How to fetch the transaction status of paypal if transaction is failed?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm getting the transaction status as completed from variable "**st**" from the URL if the transaction was the success, similarly how to get if it is canceled by the user or failed?

Here is my code,

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="{emailflexform}">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="{email}">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://192.168.xyz.yy/typo3test.local/index.php?id=69">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="{url}">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="{uid}">           
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

is it correct?

- Here is my transaction completed URL

http://192.168.xyz.yy/typo3test.local/index.php?id=69&tx=3CM23566EG4059057&st=Completed&amt=5%2e00&cc=USD&cm=tuyty%40gmail%2ecom&item_number=118&sig=MIk2dzKU3kZFuQuJ8LkJGMIDLjFWqPZZLllURpBNlYyaPtCdJYwVO5yzraLdDzfXEKDajnGtZO4YrRLpOvK0o3AMgFCHzAK%2b1R%2fSWshu3SaXVZuCxuU%2fObCmjiEs2KC9%2bEbogA9XRDePTxScN%2b8mhmRw5Nk0j1QUJ2CCqq%2fkiWo%3d

- Here is my transaction cancelled/failed URL

http://192.168.xyz.yy/typo3test.local/index.php?id=69

Comment: Where is the code you have tried so far ?

Comment: Sorry, I have added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can get from your question, from the same URL you get the status for failed and canceled the transaction.
Paypal sends complete information for each transaction whether failed or completed.There are two ways of getting the details :
1) Via return message.
2) Via IPN( Instant Payment Notifications ).

For more support, you need to provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is Complicated to understand because you are not showing your code....I hope you will get some idea from this 
https://www.paypal.com/in/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-test-failed-transactions-in-the-paypal-sandbox-ts1259